# Saving 16-bit image, spatial dimension is shrunk to half along one axis

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am acquiring multi-spectral data from specim camera, and can save it in 8-bit format without any issue. But when I am trying to save the same image in 16-bit format, the image is shrinking to half in one axis. I am using OpenCV on Linux. See my code and images (both 8 and 16 bits) below.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

```cpp
 Mat frame(FX17_HEIGHT,FX17_WIDTH, CV_16UC1);  //CV_8UC1 CV_16U

          int i,j;
          unsigned char *dest, *src;
          src = (unsigned char*) pBase;

          for( i = 0; i < FX17_HEIGHT; ++i) {
                dest = frame.ptr<uchar>(i);
                for ( j = 0; j < FX17_WIDTH; j++)
                        *(dest+j) = *(src + i*FX17_WIDTH+j);
          }

          ostringstream name;
          QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName();
          name << filename.toUtf8().constData() << "png";
          imwrite(name.str() , frame);
```

[image: images 8 and 16 bits]

Comment: `unsigned char *dest  = frame.ptr<uchar>(i);` ... but elements of `frame` are 16bit, not 8bit. | That said, I'm not really sure why you need 9 lines of code when a single [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) exists for this purpose.

Comment: I am unclear as to what you are acquiring from the camera. Do you acquire 8-bit or 16-bit? If you acquire 8-bit, what is the point of saving it as 16-bit? If you acquire as 16-bit, how could you possibly have a problem saving it as 16-bit?

Comment: thanks Mark and Dan. I solved the issue, it was basically coming from the camera configuration (not opencv issue) and yes I also changed the datatypes from char to short